# Create hyperlink to a filtered Datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint-online, datasheet

Is it possible to create a direct link to a Datasheet/quick edit view which is already filtered.
If I copy the filtered URL:

```
http://example.com/sites/sitename/list/dataentryview.aspx#InplviewHash70763fb8-1214-4171-a594-0b4e4900c6b4=ShowInGrid%3DTrue-FilterField1%3DPlant-FilterValue1%3DPlant1
```

Then if I paste this it removes the filter. This doesn't happen for normal list views, just the datasheet view. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, a link with siteID like this

```
https://orgname.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite1/Lists/Product%20list/AllItems.aspx?siteid=2bd0f42e-0f2d-4e58-bb0b-0448b40c3840&webid=537fcc6b-c61c-4bef-a447-f95ff500ef5a&uniqueid=1853b63d-8415-487f-88fb-63ebf56288f5#InplviewHash5824278e-1b91-4f89-8d77-b1d60e8c0ef3=ShowInGrid%3DTrue-FilterField1%3DCurrencies-FilterValue1%3DAUD
```

can be used to create link file in Document library to direct to a filtered datasheet view.
You may need to create the link manually.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work for a list rather than a document library. Thanks for the help though.